# Libcurl returns error 7 when trying to download from FTP

Tags: c++, libcurl

I am developing a program in C++ that downloads a file from FTP and uploads that file to another FTP server.

At first, I figured that the problem could have been because the FTP server had a password, but after removing it, there is no change. I've tried putting the username and password in `CURLOPT_URL` and in `CURLOPT_USERPWD`

Here is some source code. Please note that it is modified here so there's no personal information in it. I'm not really connecting to `example.com`.

```
struct FtpFile ftpfile = {
    "document.pdf",
    NULL
};
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://example.com/foo.pdf");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "User:Pass");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_fwrite);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &ftpfile);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    if(CURLE_OK != res) {
        printf("Oh, Fiddle Sticks. What now?\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Error Code: %d\n", res);
    }
}
curl_global_cleanup();
```

I would expect it to log into the FTP server at `example.com` with `User:Pass`. However, I get error 7 when I try to download from an FTP server.

Here is the program's output:

```
Downloading... This Device <-- Remote Server
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
* Closing connection 0
Oh Fiddle Sticks, What now?
Error Code: 7
```

I know error code 7 means that it failed to connect to the server, but every other device I have is able to connect to it. Am I missing something?

Comment: `timeout on name lookup is not supported` can you resolve the hostname?

Comment: Error 7 is `CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT` ("Failed to connect() to host or proxy"). What is unclear about that? That has nothing to do with authentication, and everything to do with the host/port you are trying to download from. You do know that `example.com` is not a real site, right? Or are you just using that as an example here (no pin intended) and your real code is using a real host?

Comment: As it says, it's modified. I probably should have been more clear, so I edited it now. In the program, the real host is my IP address and the real username and password is my username and password. The real program isn't attempting to connect to ```example.com```. I am able to resolve the hostname that is in the actual program.

Comment: Either the server you try to connect to doesn't run a server on port 25 or something (like a firewall) is blocking your TCP connect attempt to that server port.

Comment: It runs on the standard port for FTP (21). I could try disabling the firewall on the host computer temporarily, though when I get home. Another idea I thought of today is changing the passive ports from 50100-51100 to default, although that may mess it up as my router is a NAT router.